# Why is Fugu (フグ) spelled in katakana? Isn't it usually only used for english words?

Tags: katakana, irregularities-exceptions, help

i was doing some research because i have to design a logo for a japanese restaurant. I saw that people usually spell it in katakana even though you only use katakana with english words/names (to my knowledge). why is that? is it just easier to write?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/20840/why-are-the-names-of-plants-and-animals-often-written-in-katakana

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15695/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/31148/5010